# How to factorize this code whichwrite in a csv file

Tags: c#, csv

I have these class.

```
public Record1(UniqueWallPart uniqueWallpart)
{
     public readonly string field1 = "";
     public readonly string field2 = "";;
        
}

public class Record1Map : ClassMap<Record1>
{
    private Record1Map ()
    {
        Map(m => m.field1).Index(0).Name("f1");
        Map(m => m.field2).Index(1).Name("f2");
    }
}
```

And fast the same `Record2` but with other fields.

I have a class to write a list of `Record1` in a csv file

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
class writerRecord1
{
    private ImmutableArray<SegmentRecord> Record1 ;


    public string ToCsv()
    {
        using var writer = new StringWriter();
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Record1Map>();
        csv.WriteRecords(Records);
        writer.Flush();
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would like to factorize the code in order to write ToCsv in a `classWriter2`.

But in
`csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<Record1Map>();`
I must explicitely write which class I using.

How can I factorize this code?

I know that the title is not good. Coudl somebody help me to find a better title, please

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not the place to ask for refactoring code, we help with specific issues.

Comment: What _objective_ issue are you facing, and what _concrete_ improvement are you looking for?

Comment: Are you asking how to implement generics?

Comment: If you want a simple `ToCSV` function, remove `RegisterClassMap` and have it accept `List<string> headers, List<List<string>> data`, and convert your other classes to strings elsewhere

Comment: One type may have multiple class `ClassMap<>`. Either So you have to link T and it's map somehow. And registering it via a contructor may be better than making record aware of the correct mapper.

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use simple generic implementation?

Code snippet is here:

```
using CsvHelper;
using CsvHelper.Configuration;

class WriterRecord<T, TMap>
    where T: class
    where TMap: ClassMap<T>
{
    private ImmutableArray<T> Records;

    public string ToCsv<T>()
    {
        using var writer = new StringWriter();
        using var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
        csv.WriteRecords(Records);
        writer.Flush();
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

You can use this class in your code something like it

- `new WriterRecord<Record1, Record1Map>()`
- `new WriterRecord<Record2, Record2Map>()`

It works for you?

Comment: If `T` is the record it can't be register as a map `ClassMap<T>`

Comment: Understood. I see your trouble. It seems we need to create instance of `ClassMap<T>` type. It can be implemented using reflection. Give me some time for experiments...

Comment: @DragandDrop Yes, you are absolutely right. We can use generics with 2 parameters (code snippet was updated).